# Camera movement gives me motion sickness and nausea

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I‘m fairly new to Blender and I really love the program. But unfortunately, I get motion sickness after 20 minutes or so. It has to be related to the rotational movement of the camera when modelling/sculpting an object. Does anyone has some tips for me? It would be very hard for me if iI had to stop learning this great program.

Thanks a lot! Christoph

Comment: I personally prefer to choose Orbit Around Selection in the Preferences > Navigation > Orbit & Pan, maybe it will fix your nausea?

Comment: Hello you can try using Orthographic projection (Numpad 5) or changing the focal length https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyvTB.png

Comment: What type of games (that don't give you motion sickness) you usually play? Maybe it's possible to set the camera to work similarily to their interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experiencing the same thing! For me it started happening suddenly. I never had problems with Blender or video games before. but now I can't even watch tutorials! It's making learning even more difficult.

A few things that helped me:

- Using more simple/geometric models with flat textures and simple lighting.
- Drinking water instead of caffeine while working.
- Not using Blender on an empty stomach.
- Taking a break every 20 minutes or looking away from the screen every 20 seconds.
- Using a computer instead of a table or laptop.
- Snacking on things like pretzels.
- Keeping the lights on or letting sunlight in.

These don't help if I have to work all day without stopping. I'm sorry I can't offer something more tech based. I still have this problem so learning Blender has been a slow process.